# Use index array to filter another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays

```
arr = [ aaa, xxx, aaa, xxx, aaa ];

foundIn = [ 1, 3 ];
```

As you can see **foundIn** has the index numbers of **arr** that I would like to remove. How can I remove the values in **arr** using the the index values in **foundIn**

```
The output being: newArr = [ aaa, aaa, aaa ];
```

This is a simplified version of my issue.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you obtain `foundIn`? Looks like you're making an unnecessary extra step here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can utilize the native javascript `.filter()` method to solve this kind of problem.

```
var arr = ["aaa", "xxx", "aaa", "xxx", "aaa"];
var foundIn = [1, 3];
var res = arr.filter(function (eachElem, index) {
    return foundIn.indexOf(index) == -1
})

console.log(res) // ["aaa", "aaa", "aaa"]
```

#### Explanation

The callback will be executed in each loop on where this function is called (in the example above example, it will be used on `arr` variable).

Two arguments are passed into the callback. First is the **element**, and the second is the **index**. Because you need the `index`, you have to write all those two arguments, even though you are not using the first argument.

In this issue, the `index` variable is used to determine whether it exists on the `foundIn` variable or not (we use `.indexOf()` method to do the checking). If it's **not exists**, `true` will be given. So all returned element is the one which is **not exists** in the `foundIn`.

`.indexOf()` returns the index of the searched item, if it's not found, `-1` is returned.

---

If you are using es6, you can simplify the code:

```
var res = arr.filter((d, i) => foundIn.indexOf(i) == -1)
```

---

Also try this working example:

```js
var arr = ["aaa", "xxx", "aaa", "xxx", "aaa"];
var foundIn = [1, 3];
var res = arr.filter(function (eachElem, index) {
    return foundIn.indexOf(index) == -1
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(res))
// ["aaa", "aaa", "aaa"]
```

Comment: In the ES6 version you can use `.includes` for clarity

Comment: @georg: ES6 (ES2015) doesn't have `includes`. (That said, I doubt there's an ES2015-compliant engine that doesn't already have it...)

Comment: Thanks! I am still learning, would you mindexplaining what the d variable in " filter(function (d, i) " is? I know the i is the index

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have come up with something:

`arr.flatMap( (x,i) => foundIn.includes( i ) ? [] : x )`

or

`arr.filter( (_,i) => ! foundIn.includes( i )  )`

I hope you like it.

Comment: Thanks for editing / formatting my original post #Patrick-Koorevaar

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. Loop through `foundIn` in reverse index order (e.g., highest first; you could use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort it) and use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove those from the other array.
2. Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `arr` and return false for indexes you don't find in `foundIn` (but it involves re-searching `foundIn` each time)
3. Build an object with index keys (or a `Set` of the indexes in ES2015 and above) from `foundIn` with keys for the indexes, and then use `arr.filter` looking up the indexes in the map to see if they should be removed.

The first two are trivial, I'll leave the coding to you. The last one may benefit from code for explanation:

```js
var arr = ["aaa", "xxx", "aaa", "xxx", "aaa"];

var foundIn = [1, 3];

var map = Object.create(null);
foundIn.forEach(function(entry) {
  map[entry] = true;
});
arr = arr.filter(function(_, index) {
  return !map[index];
});

console.log(arr);
```

or in ES2015 (aka "ES6") and above:

```js
let arr = ["aaa", "xxx", "aaa", "xxx", "aaa"];

let foundIn = [1, 3];
let set = new Set(foundIn);
arr = arr.filter((_, index) => !set.has(index));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: "Not useful" how? Because I left the actual coding to the reader? I don't read the question as "do my work for me," I read "how do I do my work."

Answer (score -1):

you can use filter(el, index) to get that done:

```
arr.filter(function(el, index) { 
         return foundIn.indexOf(index) > -1;
 });
```

filter returns an array with all the element's which the condition returned true for them.
In my exmaple, all elements which their index exists in foundIn